# Disable glob qualifiers in zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Is there a way to disable glob qualifiers with zsh? It seems like a useful feature, but it gets in the way of normal parentheses.

I use `ag` to search files, and `ag mymethod(param)` causes zsh to complain about `missing end of name`, and I'd rather not have to quote my arguments. Since I never really use glob qualifiers, I figured I'd just disable them, but my Googling hasn't turned up any results.

Comment: `ag mymethod(param)` is a syntax error in all the other shells. Disabling one of the most powerful features of `zsh` just for that sounds a bit silly to me. Just quote that. (`ag 'mymethod(param)'` like in all the other shells).

Comment: :( yeah I'm starting to be convinced that this is a futile effort...

Comment: You can do `alias ag='noglob ag'` if you want to disable globbing in the arguments to `ag`.

Comment: I second Stéphane. What's `ag`?

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the `PATTERN(QUALIFIERS)` syntax by unsetting the [`bare_glob_qual`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-BARE_005fGLOB_005fQUAL) option:

```
setopt no_bare_glob_qual
```

If the option [`extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) is set (and you should set it, the only reason not to set it is for backward compatibility with rare scripts that use unusual syntax), then there is another syntax for glob qualifiers: `PATTERN(#qQUALIFIERS)`. So you can still use glob qualifiers, which are one of zsh's killer features, but you'll have to type a bit more.

Zsh lets you disable wildcard expansion (globbing) altogether, and this looks like a better choice for you. If a command is prefixed by `noglob`, then no globbing is performed on its arguments. For example, to be able to type URLs containing `?` as arguments to `wget`, I have `alias wget='noglob wget'`. If you set `alias ag='noglob ag'`, you can type `ag mymethod(param)`.

If `ag` takes both a search pattern and file names as arguments, then disabling globbing is not good. If you're able to parse the arguments of `ag`, then you can perform wildcard expansion on them. I don't know the syntax of `ag`, so I'll give an example where I assume that `ag` only takes options that don't take arguments, and that its first non-option argument is a pattern and the rest are files.

```
ag () {
local i=1
  while [[ ${(P)i} = -* ]]; do ((++i)); done
  if ((i < $#)); then
    set -- "${(@)@[1,$i]}" $~@[$((i+1)),$#]
  fi
}
alias ag='noglob ag'
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `SH_GLOB` option.

```
setopt sh_glob
```

From `man zshoptions`:

> SH_GLOB  
>                 Disables  the  special meaning of `(', `|', `)' and `<' for globbing the result of parameter and command
>                 substitutions, and in some other places where the  shell  accepts  patterns.   If  SH_GLOB  is  set  but
>                 KSH_GLOB  is not, the shell allows the interpretation of subshell expressions enclosed in parentheses in
>                 some cases where there is no space before the opening parenthesis, e.g. !(true)  is  interpreted  as  if
>                 there were a space after the !.  This option is set by default if zsh is invoked as sh or ksh.

Comment: Is the right command `setopt sh_glob`? (zsh can't find a `shopt` command) I tried setopt but it still complains zsh: missing end of name.

Comment: @Josh Yes, the name is `setopt`.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the correction; muscle memory is hard to overcome :)

Comment: can this option be added `~/.zshrc` somehow?

Comment: Useful to remember that this option is set when zsh is invoked by `sh`.